intersection points, line and contour
For this question, I refer to the post connect sides by arrows in any contour, polygonal figure, closed curve, etc.
Here is the code modified by me. What I want is to mark each intersection point of the line L with the blue contour vertical lines.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, calc}
\tikzset{
    marks/.style 2 args={
        postaction=decorate, 
        decoration={
            markings, mark=between positions {1/(#1+1)} and {(#1)/(#1+1)} step {1/(#1+1)} with {
                \coordinate[name=#2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}];
            }
        }
    },
    midarrow/.style={postaction=decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}}
}

\newcommand{\contour}[6][]{% #1=tikz options, #2=num lines, #3=start, #4=end, #5=bottom, #6=top
    \draw[marks={#2}{A}, #1] #3;
    \draw[marks={#2}{B}, #1] #4;
    \draw[marks={4}{C}, midarrow, #1] #5;
    \draw[marks={4}{D}, midarrow, #1] #6;
    \foreach \l in {1,...,#2}{
        \draw[smooth, midarrow, #1] plot coordinates {(A\l)
            ($($(A\l)!{.2}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C1)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D1)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.4}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C2)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D2)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.6}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C3)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D3)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.8}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C4)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D4)$)$)
            (B\l)};
    }
}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\tikzset{
    on each segment/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            moveto code={},
            lineto code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            curveto code={
                \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                .. controls
                (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
                ..
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            closepath code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
        },
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\contour[blue, thick,name path =plotA]{8}
    {(0,0) to[bend left] (2,6)}
    {[looseness=2] (4,1) to[out=45, in=225] (5,5)}
    {(0,0) -- (4,1)}
    {(2,6) to[bend right] (5,5)}
     \draw[thick,xshift=0.61cm,name path=plotB,yshift=-4cm,xshift=0.6cm](2.5,4.5) to [out=90,in=-90] ++ (0,5) node[anchor=0]{$L$};
    \fill[blue,name intersections={of=plotB and plotA}]
            (intersection-3) circle[radius=2pt] node[right,yshift=-0.3cm] {$m$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I wanted the 3rd intersection point, for instance, and I ve got this:


Instead of trying to name the entire plot, name each curve in the \contour macro. Then you can use intersections to identify the desired point.
Note: I removed much of your code that was unnecessary, for example, you were loading tikz twice, as well as several libraries. The style on each segment is not used.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, calc, intersections}
\tikzset{
    marks/.style 2 args={
        postaction=decorate, 
        decoration={
            markings, mark=between positions {1/(#1+1)} and {(#1)/(#1+1)} step {1/(#1+1)} with {
                \coordinate[name=#2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}];
            }
        }
    },
    midarrow/.style={postaction=decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}}
}

\newcommand{\contour}[6][]{% #1=tikz options, #2=num lines, #3=start, #4=end, #5=bottom, #6=top
    \draw[marks={#2}{A}, #1] #3;
    \draw[marks={#2}{B}, #1] #4;
    \draw[marks={4}{C}, midarrow, #1] #5;
    \draw[marks={4}{D}, midarrow, #1] #6;
    \foreach \l in {1,...,#2}{
        \draw[smooth, midarrow, #1, name path=curve\l] plot coordinates {(A\l)
            ($($(A\l)!{.2}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C1)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D1)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.4}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C2)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D2)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.6}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C3)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D3)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.8}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C4)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D4)$)$)
            (B\l)};
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\contour[blue, thick,name path =plotA]{8}
    {(0,0) to[bend left] (2,6)}
    {[looseness=2] (4,1) to[out=45, in=225] (5,5)}
    {(0,0) -- (4,1)}
    {(2,6) to[bend right] (5,5)}
     \draw[thick, name path=myline](3.7,.5) to [out=90,in=-90] ++ (0,5) node[anchor=0]{$L$};
     \fill[blue, name intersections={of=myline and curve3}]
            (intersection-1) circle[radius=2pt] node[below right]{$m$};   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

